# how to preserve pandas dataframe identity when extracting a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting a subset of my dataframe by index using either .xs or .loc (they seem to behave the same). When my condition retrieves multiple rows, the result stays a dataframe. When only a single row is retrieved, it is automatically converted to a series. I don't want that behavior, since that means I need to handle multiple cases downstream (different method sets available for series vs dataframe).

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(7), 'b':['one']*4 + ['two'] + ['three']*2,
 'c':range(10,17)})

In [2]: df.set_index('b', inplace=True)

In [3]: df.xs('one')
Out[3]:
     a   c
b
one  0  10
one  1  11
one  2  12
one  3  13

In [4]: df.xs('two')
Out[4]:
a     4
c    14
Name: two, dtype: int64

In  [5]: type(df.xs('two'))
Out [5]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I can manually convert that series back to a dataframe, but it seems cumbersome and will also require case testing to see if I should do that. Is there a cleaner way to just get a dataframe back to begin with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply add braces, `[]`, and use `.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc["two"]
a     4
c    14
Name: two, dtype: int64
>>> type(_)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> df.loc[["two"]]
     a   c
b         
two  4  14

[1 rows x 2 columns]
>>> type(_)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

This may remind you of how `numpy` advanced indexing works:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> a[1]
array([3, 4, 5])
>>> a[[1]]
array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

Now this will probably require some refactoring of code so that you're always accessing with a list, even if the list only has one element, but it works well for me in practice.